# Loop to match lists of names and populate a new variable according to the gender of the names

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

Suppose I have the following lists, where "names" is a full list of names (say, in a class):

```
names<-as.matrix(c("Paul", "Tyler", "Roberta", "Greg", "Tiffany"))
```

Suppose I have a secondary list of names, this one only including "female" names:

```
female_names<-as.matrix(c("Roberta", "Tiffany", "Michelle", "Ashley"))
```

I am attempting to create another variable, "women", that takes the value 1 if the element in "names" matches one of the "female names" in the second list from above.

```
women<-as.matrix(rep(0, 5))

for(i in 1:nrow(names)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(female_names)){
    if(names[i,1]==female_names[j,1]){women[i]<-1}
  }
}
```

However, when I summarize the new variable women, all values are 0, which should not be the case.

```
summary(women)
```

However, my problem is that none of the female names are being identified correctly and receiving the corresponding value of 1 for the new women variable. ***How can I correctly execute this loop to match the names and populate my new variable accordingly?***

Comment: While I would recommend Ananda's answer, your logic actually works fine for me.  I get a column matrix with 1s in the 3rd and 5th rows.  What happens for you?

Comment: @BrodieG, reading the rest of the question, perhaps it is that they *might* be looking for `table(women[, 1])` rather than `summary`...

Comment: @BrodieG

All I get in my results are 0's, which should not be the case IF my conditional statement in the loop is actually formulated correctly. It is odd that you got a proper result from the example code above because the loop works neither for the example above or my actual data either.

I generally agree accepting Ananda's answer, but I am still sort of confused as to why the general approach above does not execute properly.

Comment: @DVHughes, Your example code works for me too.

Comment: @DVHughes, why don't you try clearing your workspace (though this shouldn't really make a difference), and re-running your code as you have it in this question (just copy and paste from here).  Then, just view the contents of `women` (don't use `summary`), and let us know if that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use `%in%`:

```
> names[, 1] %in% female_names[, 1]
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can wrap the whole thing in `as.numeric` if you prefer 1s and 0s instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
> as.numeric(names[, 1] %in% female_names[, 1])
[1] 0 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to the question you asked but maybe this is a better answer.

The dev version of [qdap](https://github.com/trinker/qdap) has a names to sex function (`name2sex`) that may be of interest:

```
names<-c("Paul", "Tyler", "Roberta", "Greg", "Tiffany")
name2sex(names)

## > name2sex(names)
## [1] M M F M F

## OR....

name2sex(names, USE.NAMES=TRUE)

## > name2sex(names, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
##    Paul   Tyler Roberta    Greg Tiffany 
##       M       M       F       M       F
```

And to get the numeric values:

```
## 2 - as.numeric(name2sex(names))

## > 2 -as.numeric(name2sex(names))
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: +1. I couldn't remember where I had seen that function. Must have been when I was looking through some of your code on Git Hub....

Comment: @Tyler Rinker does this function work with names in other languages? Special characters, etc.?

Comment: If you use `?name2sex` you'll see that the description says `Predict gender from U.S. names (based on 1990 U.S. census data).`